# Dynamic Time Warping with fast lookup?

Tags: python, dynamic-time-warping

My understanding of Dynamic Time Warping is that the algorithm always requires calculation with each comparison/training series and that there is no way to extract the "essence" from a given training series in the form of coefficients, which could then be compared to coefficients for the test series similar to what might be possible with different wavelet transforms, Discrete Cosine Transform, etc.  In experimenting with Python's `fastdtw` package, DTW does appear to be somewhat slow (despite the name of the package).

What I'm wondering is whether there are any methods that produce coefficients that still preserve the dynamic warping aspect.  Perhaps there are certain modifications to wavelet transforms that could do the trick?

Comment: I think your understanding is correct. But then I don't understand what kind of coefficient you would like to obtain? DTW compares two time series, so unless the two time series are predefined there's no way to shorten the comparison. Afaik the only efficiency trick that can be used is to resample the time series.

Comment: I'm just comparing it to something like a wavelet transform or DCT, which produces coefficients without needing a comparison.  However, I don't believe that either of those methods can effectively deal with the time warping aspect.